# Running PHP on Windows with Apache2

Tags: php, apache2

I am new to PHP and have been trying to get a PHP application setup on Windows.

I have installed MySql5.1, Apache2.2 and PHP5.2.14 on Windows Server 2008. I can login into MySql no problem and I can run phpinfo from htdocs in apache and get the php config summary however whenever I copy in my application to htdocs and run it I get a blank page.

I have set my DirectyIndex in httpd to welcome.php but nothing .... any help troubleshooting would be great.

Comment: Did you spell `DirectoryIndex` correctly in your httpd.conf?  Did you try hitting `welcome.php` directly?

Comment: yep ..spelled correctly and yes did try directly. If phpinfo works does that mean apache is configured right?

Comment: Should be on server fault, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you turn on all error display in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

then see if the application still gives you a blank page.  If it still does, then it maybe configuration error on apache/php.  Since, you are able to display phpinfo i would say the configuration works.  perhaps, there's an error on the application.

Comment: Thanks. I got errors but in the end installed wamp. All working now. Thanks